# Typescript instantiate generic object

Tags: generics, typescript

I have this problem, and search for hours and can't find the right solution for it.
I'm trying to create a generic function that revives an type and an object and convert the object to that specific type. but I'm having troubles to instantiate the generic type. I would like to know if there are something like in c# Activator.CreateInstance

```
handleResult<T>(response: Response):T {
    let jsonResp = response.json();
    let obj = jsonResp as Object;
    let resp: T = Object.CreateInstance(T); //        
    doTheMambo(resp, obj);
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: What does `response.json()` return? An object, or a string representation of that object? And if it returns an object directly, what are the differences between that object and `T` that you hope to resolve in your `doTheMambo`?

Comment: The response.json returns a json, an the doTheMambo will make some sort of parse between the two objects.

Comment: The two objects can have major differences between thems

Comment: There's no way to use `T` in runtime so you can't pass it. Can you please describe better what is the json you're using and what's the object you want to create?

Answer (score 2):

In typescript, generic parameters are erased during the compilation and there is no trace of them in generated javascript code. So there's nothing like `CreateInstance` from c#.

But, again unlike c#, classes in typescript can be used at runtime just like any other objects, so if all you need is to create an instance of a class at runtime you can do that pretty easily (note that it applies only to classes, not to any type in general).

The syntax for [generic class type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) looks a bit unusual: it's a literal type written as `{new(...args: any[]): T}`

Here is complete (it compiles) example that does something like you described in your question. For simplification, I supposed that all objects that need to be instantiated must conform to common `interface Result` (otherwise you have to do type cast to some known type in doTheMambo to do something useful).

```
interface Response { json(): any }

interface Result { kind: string }

function handleResult<T extends Result>(tClass: { new (...args: any[]): T }, response: Response): T {
    let jsonResp = response.json();
    let obj = jsonResp;
    let resp: T = new tClass();        
    doTheMambo(resp, obj);
    return resp;
}

class Result1 {
    kind = 'result1';
}

function doTheMambo<T extends Result>(response: T, obj: any) {
    console.log(response.kind);
}

const r: Result = handleResult(Result1, { json() { return null } });
```