# Create instances from static method of generic class

Tags: typescript

I want to have base model:

```
export class BaseModel<T> {
   public static create(obj:any):T {
      let instance = _.assignIn(new T(), obj);
      return instance;   
   }
}
```

and then, specific model:

```
export class MyModel: BaseModel<MyModel> {
   public prop1:string;
}
```

then, I want to create models in the following way:

```
let myModel = MyModel.create(...);
```

But, I can't force it work and get error:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript instantiate generic object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261472/typescript-instantiate-generic-object)

Comment: My case is different.

Comment: The solution is the same - add another parameter to `create`.  Define it like `create(cls: {new(): T}, obj: any) { ... assignIn(new cls(), obj); ...}`, use it like `MyModel.create(MyModel, ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the generic constraint as a value, it does not exist in runtime, so this:

```
new T()
```

Makes no sense.

You can do this:

```
class BaseModel {
    public static create<T extends BaseModel>(obj: any): T {
        let instance = Object.assign(new this(), obj);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20BaseModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20create%3CT%20extends%20BaseModel%3E(obj%3A%20any)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20instance%20%3D%20Object.assign(new%20this()%2C%20obj)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20instance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyModel%20extends%20BaseModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D))

Then

```
let myModel = MyModel.create<MyModel>(...);
```

Will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,